# Trigger JQuery UI Datepicker from Function and store date into a var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, frameworks

I need your help.

Is it programmatically possible to use the Jquery picker, ie. trigger the datepicker by calling a function and then store the selected date into a var as opposed to a hidden input box?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

The current example that I have triggers the date picker from a function but uses a hidden input box.

```
<html>

<head>

<!-- LOAD JQUERY LIBRARY: -->  
    <link   href="jq/jquery-ui.css"         type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jq/jquery.min.js"          type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="jq/jquery-ui.min.js"       type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function test() {

$("#d1").datepicker().datepicker("show");




}

</script>



</head>

<body>

<input style="display: none" type="text" id="d1">

<a href="javascript:test()">test</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attach it to a div instead of an input control.

[The JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2Zsu/).

The HTML:

```
<div id="d1"></div>

<a href="#" id="test">test</a>
```

The JS:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    var datePickerValue = null;

    $("#d1").datepicker().datepicker("show").change(function ()
    {
      datePickerValue = $(this).val();
      alert("You picked: " + datePickerValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: I was just curious to know if the date picker will always require an input box or if I can just open the datepicker and store the selected date into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in this fiddle, although it looks ugly with the hidden input box.

http://jsfiddle.net/QfjP5/